# converting a hexadecimal number correctly in a decimal number (also negatives)

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, negative-number

As the headline supposes I am trying to convert hex numbers like 0x320000dd to decimal numbers. 
My code only works for positive numbers but fails when it comes to hex numbers that represent negative decimal numbers. Here is a excerpt of my code:

```
         cin>>hex>> x;
         unsigned int number = x;
         int r = number & 0xffffff;
```

My input is alreay in hex, and the computer converts it automatically in an integer. What I am trying to do is getting the operand of the hex number, so the last 24 bits. 
Can you help me get my code working for negative values like :0x32fffdc9 or 0x32ffffff? Thank's a lot!

EDIT:

I would like my output to be :
0x32fffdc9 --> -567
or
0x32ffffff --> -1

so just the plain decimal values but instead it gives me 16776649 and 16777215 for the upper examples.

Comment: @kiner_shah hex is std::hex most likely.

Comment: @Borgleader, got it! :-)

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I missed to tell you, that I included 'using namespace std;' in my code. so the std::hex wouldn't change anything, right? :)

Comment: @Jennan can you add what *output* you want?

Comment: so you want interpret a 24-bit value as `int`? you probably need to check the sign bit (and do the conversion) yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative integers are typically stored in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) Meaning that if your most significant bit (MSB) is not set the number is not negative. This means that just as you need to unset the 8-MSBs of your number to clamp a 32-bit number to a 24-bit positive number, so you'll need to *set* the 8-MSBs of your number to clamp to a negative number:

```
const int32_t r = 0x800000 & number ? 0xFF000000 | number : number & 0xFFFFFF;
```

`vector<bool>` or `bitset` may be worth your consideration, as they would clarify the hexadecimal numbers to the range of bits to be set.

Comment: Thank you for your answere, I am not understanding it completely since english is not my mother tongue, and also I am programming with an older version of c++ which doesn't allow me to use int32_t, but what you are saying is getting the MSB which in the case of 0x32ffffff would be the first f after thw 2, right? and evaluete if it is 8 or higher which would imply a negative number. Did I understand that correctly?
Also, after I know wheter it is a negative or not, I can't just put a '-' infront of the value, right? I need to calculate differenlty is that correct?

Comment: @Jennan 1) If your compiler can't handle `int32_t` you should place more value on using a standard container 2) Yes, I'm saying that the MSB of your 24-bit integer will define whether it's negative 3) No, you cannot simply negate the 24-bit integer to get it's negative representation, the `-` performs the 2's complement operation, and you don't want your 24-bit integer to be modified, so you'll need to do it with the masks.